# How to show downsampled values in grafana ?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a influxdb and want to show the downsampled values on grafana.

> InfluxDB Version: 1.2
>
> Grafana Version: 4.2

- I have created a influxedb database:

  ```
  > CREATE DATABASE "mydb3_rp"
  ```
- Then I have created an retention policy:

  ```
  > CREATE RETENTION POLICY "1week" ON "mydb3_rp" DURATION 1w REPLICATION 1
  ```
- Then I have created the continuous query:

  ```
  create continuous query "cq_10" on mydb3_rp begin 
    select mean(\*) into "mydb3_rp"."1week".:MEASUREMENT 
    from /.\*/ 
    group by time(10m),* 
  end
  ```
- Then I put some data into the database. When I finished and want to see the saved values with the influx command line tool :

  ```
  select * from cpu1
  name: cpu1
  time                 cluster        node  value
  ----                 -------        ----  -----
  2017-05-03T17:06:00Z cluster-2 node2 2.9552020666133956
  2017-05-03T17:07:00Z cluster-2 node2 -1.5774569414324822
  2017-05-03T17:08:00Z cluster-2 node2 0.16813900484349714
  2017-05-03T17:09:00Z cluster-2 node2 1.244544235070617
  2017-05-03T17:10:00Z cluster-1 node2 7.833269096274834
  2017-05-03T17:10:00Z cluster-2 node2 -5.440211108893697
  2017-05-03T17:11:00Z cluster-1 node2 -6.877661591839738
  and so on...
  ```
- And now I want to see, if the continuous query was working and did the aggregation:

  ```
  select * from "1week".cpu1
  name: cpu1
  time                 cluster        mean_value           node
  ----                 -------        ----------           ----
  2017-05-03T16:45:00Z cluster-1 1.074452901375393    node1
  2017-05-03T16:45:00Z cluster-2 1.477524301989568    node1
  2017-05-03T16:45:00Z cluster-1 0.8845193960173319   node2
  2017-05-03T16:45:00Z cluster-2 -0.6551129796659627  node2
  2017-05-03T16:50:00Z cluster-2 -1.6457347223119738  node1
  2017-05-03T16:50:00Z cluster-2 0.6789712320493559   node2
  ...and so on
  ```
- Now I go into grafana and define a query like this :

  ```
  FROM 1week cpu1
  select field(value)
  ```

There are -  **No Data Points**

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question was asked two months ago, but maybe someone is still reading this.
I'm currently struggling with this too and found a working query in my case. In yours I think it should be:

```
select "mean_value" from "mydb3_rp"."1week"."cpu1" where $timeFilter
```

And other `where` conditions if you wan't to be more specific.

K.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why this answer is not useful?
Backreferenced continuous query obviously worked and in this case to retreive mean_value one should use fully qualified measurement. This is the correct approach in my opinion and it works well in my instllation.

Comment: I forgot the database name before retention policy, corrected.